# Preg_replace a specific strings first character

Tags: php, preg-replace, php-8

I have a `string` of "You can go to kitchen and get some food for your dinner" and i need to change with `preg_replace` words `You, your, food` case insensitive to `<i>y</i>ou,<i>y</i>our,<i>f</i>ood`

Is there i a pattern to match first character of a specific words in the `string`? Can someone give examples

input text not matching

Comment: Probably a better way to do this, but matching `(?i)\b(?|(y)(ou)|(y)(our)|(f)(ood))\b` and replacing with `<i>$1</i>$2` should work.

Comment: That's the perfect answer, thanks

Comment: @CAustin add this as an answer please i will choose that for the right answer

Answer (score -1):

You can generalize the pattern to just match words using the `\b` word boundary class, use `preg_replace_callback()`, and a list of target words to make this more easily extensible. Eg:

```php
$input = "You can go to kitchen and get some food for your dinner";

$pattern ='/\b(\w)(\w+)\b/i';

$whitelist = ['you', 'your', 'food'];

$output = preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern,
    function($a)use($whitelist){
        if( in_array(strtolower($a[0]), $whitelist) ) {
            return sprintf('<i>%s<\i>%s', $a[1], $a[2]);
        } else {
            return $a[0];
        }
    },
    $input
);

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
string(76) "<i>Y<\i>ou can go to kitchen and get some <i>f<\i>ood for <i>y<\i>our dinner"
```

Comment: I have test code and the result is `Y<\i>ou can go to kitchen and get some f<\i>ood for y<\i>our dinner` there is no opening tag